# Flashing when using jQuery mouseenter() and mouseleave()

Tags: jquery, css

Following advice from several answers I switched from using `hover()` to `mouseover()` to finally `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()`. Yet I STILL get the flashing problem (when hovering the `.staff_img` image element, the `mouseleave()` event keeps firing every second. What am I doing wrong?

JS

```
$('.staff_img').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.staff_hover').fadeIn();
});
$('.staff_img').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.staff_hover').fadeOut();
});
```

HTML

```
<img class="staff_img" />
<div class="staff_hover"></div>
```

CSS

```
.staff img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.staff_hover {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle here so that it is easy to check.

Comment: Have you considered just using CSS `.staff_img:hover+.staff_hover { display:block }`?

Comment: That's because `.staff_hover` is covering the image and so the mouseleave event is fired and then the mouseenter is fired again and so on... What is expected behaviour?! You could set `pointer-events` to `none` for the covering element if no interaction is needed but still, what are you expecting here?

Comment: And usually, we wrap both elements in a common container and bind events on this container

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that the `staff_hover` div is going on top of the image which trigger the mouseleave on the image, then the div will disappear again and trigger the mousenter, etc. That's why it's flashing.

You may add z-index to `staff_hover` to make it below the image and avoid this issue :

```js
$('.staff_img').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.staff_hover').fadeIn();
});
$('.staff_img').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.staff_hover').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.staff_img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.staff_hover {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index:-99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="staff_img" src="https://lorempixel.com/200/100/" />
<div class="staff_hover"></div>
```

And if you want to cover the image with an overlay you may simply use some CSS transition like this :

```css
.staff_img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.staff_hover {
  position: relative;
}

.staff_hover:before {
  content:"";
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition:1s;
}

.staff_hover:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="staff_hover">
  <img class="staff_img" src="https://lorempixel.com/200/100/" />
</div>
```

Comment: Ya it could be what OP is looking for, changing the background but it is really not clear regarding the question. OP just didn't provide info regarding what is his expected behaviour

Comment: @A.Wolff yes sure, i added z-index so he can simply understand what's goiing on ... but am sure he wants an overlay on the image so i provided another solution too

Comment: I guess it is what OP is looking for now :)

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is that overlay goes above image (i guess, because it is overlay?), one possible solution would be to get position of image, calculate width and height, get mouse/cursor position on mousemove, and do something like this:

```
    pos=$('.staff_img').position();
    pos_x=pos.left
    pos_y=pos.top

     w=$('.staff_img').width();
     h=$('.staff_img').height();




  $( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {

    if((event.pageX>=pos_x && event.pageX<pos_x+w) && (event.pageY>=pos_y && event.pageY<pos_y+h )) {
    $('.staff_hover').fadeIn();
    }
    else {
    $('.staff_hover').fadeOut();
    }
    });
```

Demo:

```js
pos=$('.staff_img').position();
pos_x=pos.left
pos_y=pos.top

w=$('.staff_img').width();
h=$('.staff_img').height();


$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {

if((event.pageX>=pos_x && event.pageX<pos_x+w) && (event.pageY>=pos_y && event.pageY<pos_y+h )) {
$('.staff_hover').fadeIn();
}
else {
$('.staff_hover').fadeOut();
}
});
```

```css
.staff img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.staff_hover {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="staff_img" src='http://placehold.it/200x200'>
<div class="staff_hover"></div>
```

But, i guess that your image and overlay have same dimensions, and that both are placed inside some container, so, this is complete unnecesary. Maybe it will help someone, anyway... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your codes works fine, only when you want `.staff_hover` to appear after `.staff_img` on `mouseenter()`, in that case just change the `z-index` of `.staff_hover` as in below codes,

```js
$('.staff_img').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.staff_hover').fadeIn();
});
$('.staff_img').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.staff_hover').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.staff img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.staff_hover {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  z-index:-1; /*Add this*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="staff_img" src="https://lorempixel.com/200/100/"/>
<div class="staff_hover"></div>
```

And if you want `.staff_hover` to appear `before .staff_image` then you need to change your jQuery little bit. Which hides `.staff_hover` on `mouseleave()`, as in below codes.

```js
$('.staff_img').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.staff_hover').fadeIn();
});
$('.staff_hover').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

```css
.staff img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.staff_hover {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  z-index:9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="staff_img" src="https://lorempixel.com/200/100/"/>
<div class="staff_hover"></div>
```

Comment: Did this stop flashing when hover .staff_img.